# (Jailbreak iOS dev) iOS daemon not working

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am developing an iOS application for jailbroken iPhone. Being a launch daemon it needs to run when the phone starts.
So here is the problem, the plist for the daemon has been placed in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons, and the .app in /Applications, by Cydia, when the package is downloaded. When the phone is rebooted the application does NOT run.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

P.S. The application runs perfectly on phone reboot, when I manually place the files using SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! Permissions of both the .app and the .plist get changed from root user to normal user when the application is packaged to a .deb for Cydia upload.

The solution:Add a script to change the permissions to root when the package is installed in the device.

Comment: Did you fix this by putting a `chown` command in your `DEBIAN/postinst` script?  Please be specific about how you solved your problem.  Also, you can **accept** your own answer as the solution, so people know that you don't still need help.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nate Yes I used `chown` command in a postinst script, to change the ownership to root wheel